# summing matrices that are inside objects in r

Tags: r, matrix, lapply

I have a list of objects. Each object has a matrix. I would like to perform matrix summation over all objects. Currently, I do it by combining "Reduce" and "lapply", where lapply takes a function that extracts the matrix from each object.

Is there a more efficient way to implement this?

Dummy example:

```
mat_1 = matrix(data = c(rep(0.01,4),rep(0.29,4)), nrow = 4, ncol = 2)

mat_2 = matrix(data = c(rep(0.1,4),rep(0.2,4)), nrow = 4, ncol = 2)

obj_1 = list(name = "obj1", my_mat = mat_1) class(obj_1) = "my_obj"

obj_2 = list(name = "obj2", my_mat = mat_2) class(obj_2) = "my_obj"

list_of_my_objs = list(obj_1,obj_2)


get_mat_from_obj = function(my_obj) {   
    return(my_obj$my_mat) 
}

Reduce('+', lapply(list_of_my_objs,get_mat_from_obj))
```

Comment: You can avoid using a custom function with `Reduce('+', lapply(list_of_my_objs, '[[', 'my_mat'))))`

Comment: thank you Reno! This is definitely more elegant! Is it also the fastest solution?